#  How to use "social disparity"

Tags: nouns, word-order

How should the phrase *social disparity* be used in a sentence?

> There was great **social disparity** between A and B.
>
> The **social disparity** was great between A and B.

Answer (score 6):

You can say either.

I just find *The social disparity was great between A and B*  strange because I wouldn't split *disparity* and *between A and B* (So I'd say *The social disparity between A and B was great*). I can't explain why though and not being a native speaker of English I might be wrong here.

Comment: I agree, word order is less standard in that one. It is OK but lays some extra emphasis on *great*. It's hard to explain.

Comment: I think that "great" can more easily be misinterpreted as "outstanding" or "excellent" (vs. "large") in the second version than in the first.